# how to run background function after response return from web.py

Tags: python, web.py

I would like to know, Is it possible to run a function after response from web.py service, which function takes long time to run?

Lets say some example as below.

**file Name: code.py**

```
import web

import time 

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:

    def GET(self):

        try:
           with open('filename.txt', 'a') as file:
                for i in range(100):
                    time.sleep(1)
                    file.write("No of times: {}".format(i))
           return "some json response"
        except:
            return "Exception occurred"

if __name__ == "__main__":     
     app.run()
```

When I run the above code, obviously it will take time because as we are using time module for sleep one sec and then write into file. So, I should wait 100 seconds for get the response from service.

I want to skip this 100 seconds waiting time.

**Expected:** First return response to client and then run this part in background?

Can somebody provide some solution. Thanks..

Comment: use python `threading` module. Let the file save work in separate thread and your current thread will return to response as normal.

Comment: Sending file write in background will mean you won't be able to `return "Exception occurred"` is that fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [python documentation for `Thread.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

Note:
With background task you won't be able to `return "Exception occurred"` as you're doing now. I believe you're OK with it.

Here's a small easy solution. There are other ways too but I feel you should explore more by yourself since you're a python beginner. :)

```
import web
import time 

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:

    def writeToFile():
     try:
       with open('filename.txt', 'a') as file:
            for i in range(100):
                time.sleep(1)
                file.write("No of times: {}".format(i))
       # Log completion
    except:
        # Log error

    def GET(self):
        thread = Thread(target=writeToFile)
        thread.start()

        return {<myJSON>}

if __name__ == "__main__":     
     app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks. This simple solution helped me in understanding of thread module as well as running  function in background after response. Really helped me a lot.

Comment: @Uday  Glad it helped. FYI: If you feel any answer helped you please upvote and mark as accepted. :)